# Database SQL Query - #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I add extra column to one of my table and i have to update this extra column according to data from another table by matching qText columns of both table.

As clarify if qtext is same in both column, update ytype column in worksets from yetkinlik table.

```
update worksets set yType=(select ytype from yetkinlik) where qText =(select qText from yetkinlik);
```

This sql codes give me error like

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have sub-queries that return multiple results.  That's the problem that you error message is reporting.  If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, your query should be more like:

```
UPDATE w
SET yType = y.yType
FROM worksets w
  INNER JOIN yetkinlik y
    ON w.qText= y.qText
```

This should update the worksets table based on matching data from the yetkinlik table.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM worksets w INNER JOIN yetkinlik y ON w.qText= y.qText' at line 3

Comment: Whoops.  I was in SQL Server mode.  That would be the right SQL Server answer.

Comment: What should i do then?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a few months, but I believe in MySql it's something more like: UPDATE worksets INNER JOIN yetkinlik ON worksets.qText = yetkinlik.qText SET worksets.yType = yetkinlik.qText

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
yType=(select ytype from yetkinlik)
```

in this case; this can potentially bring back multiple results.

Instead consider

```
yType=(select ytype from yetkinlik limit 1)
```

... or something along those lines.  Additionally,

```
qText =(select qText from yetkinlik)
```

should look like

```
qText in (select qText from yetkinlik)
```

... or something along those lines.